# Как обновить ядро Linux в дестрибутиве liberte

Tags: linux, администрирование, ядро, cd

Как обновить ядро Linux в дистрибутиве liberte CD желательно без потерь анонимности и защищенности. Вайфай не работает в дистрибутиве.

Comment: вероятно, наименее трудозатратный путь — просто [пересобрать весь liveusb](https://dee.su/liberte-build)

Comment: А как это сделать?

Comment: я привёл ссылку на инструкцию.